# Pass variable from an activity to a java class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to pass an int from FirstActivity to TheAdapter(not an activity). When a button is clicked in FirstActivity, it opens SecondActivity, which creates an instance of TheAdapter, displaying its contents in a list view.

FirstActivity:

```
viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number = 5; //this is an integer
            Intent in = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

SecondActivity:

```
TheAdapter adapter = new TheAdapter(this, 0);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to get the integer from FirstActivity so i can use it in TheAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Activity:

```
viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        number = 5; //this is an integer
        Intent in = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("name of your value (eg. adapter_int)", number);
        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int yourInt = intent.getExtra("name of your value (eg. adapter_int)", 0); // 0 is a default value
```

Comment: That worked and I passed it into the other class via its constructor, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent in = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
in.putExtra(Key , value);
startActivity(in);
```

// in SecondActivity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

//for example int param
int param = 0;
if(bundle == null){
     Log.e(TAG, "bundle is null.");
}else{
     param = bundle.getInt(key);
}
```

if you want pass object (serializable object) it should be useful

```
public class Serializer {

public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        try(ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)){
            o.writeObject(obj);
        }
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try(ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)){
        try(ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b)){
            return o.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: and you can add parameter default value to bundle.getInt(key , defaultValue)